# Have to create a Column with Unique constraint in the already made table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to add a column with Unique constraint in the already made table. The Column should have default value as combination of two other columns such as Posted_By and Posted_DateTime.

How to implement it through sql query ?

Comment: OK - so what's the question?

Comment: How to implement it through sql query ?

Comment: This is a question for google, not fot stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution might be to create the column, populate it, and then alter it to be unique.  Make sense?

Here is some untested code:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD COLUMNNAME VARCHAR(100) NULL;

UPDATE TABLENAME 
SET COLUMNNAME = Posted_By + CAST(Posted_DateTime as Varchar)

ALTER TABLE TABLENAME  ADD CONSTRAINT
CONSTRAINTNAME UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ( COLUMNNAME )
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks you very much but there is a bit issue I have implemented it like

Comment: UPDATE feedbacks 
SET FB_Dup =CAST( Posted_By as varchar(max)) + CAST(Post_Date as Varchar(max))+ ISNULL( CAST(FacebookPageAndWallMesssage_ID as Varchar(max)),ID)

Comment: ALTER TABLE feedbacks  ADD CONSTRAINT
FB_DUP_MSG UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ( FB_Dup )

Comment: but got Msg 1919, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'FB_Dup' in table 'feedbacks' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

Comment: @PragatiSingh You can not have a unique constraint on a `(n)varchar(max)` column. Unique constraints in SQL Server is enforced by an index and the [Maximum Size of Index Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241(v=sql.105).aspx) is 900 bytes. That will allow you to use at most a `varchar(900)` or `nvarchar(450)` for a column used in a unique constraint.